# URL rewrite in tomcat web.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I would like to automatically redirect requests for http://example.com  to http://example.com/SomePage

I am able to do that with Apache with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /SomePage [R]
```

However, some of my servers do not run on top of Apache, just Tomcat.  How do I implement the equivalent in web.xml? SomePage is a struts2 action.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tomcat alone instead of with Apache with modrewrite, the best approach is to install a rewrite filter and reference it from your web.xml.  One filter I have used in the past is UrlRewriteFilter from tuckey.org (http://www.tuckey.org/).

It is on Google Code at http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/source/browse/trunk/src/test-web/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml.

Last update was in October 2010, but I do remember it working just fine.  Config files are XMLish, not the nice one liners that you use in modrewrite.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that if possible.  I could write my own servlet to do the redirect, which I was trying to avoid as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is any native Tomcat solution for URL rewriting.  I think you will find UrlRewrite easy to use.  Perhaps someone else has another solution?

Comment: Why not use an index page that redirects to your first struts action, place the index page in your war file and create a `welcome` section in your web.xml. It's one more server roundtrip but easy to implement using standard servlet API functionality

Comment: @home Good point, that definitely works for redirecting the welcome page using only the servlet API.  Guess I was thinking of a more general solution. +1

Answer (score -1):

I would just use `<welcome-file-list>` in the web.xml.  For example

```
<welcome-file-list>    
  <welcome-file>SomePage.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: "SomePage is a struts2 action." - not a static `.html` file, so this can't work.