# How to remove trailing slash from embedded Jetty URLs?

Tags: embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I use embedded Jetty 9.3.8.v20160314 from Scala (Scala is incidental here, this is a pure Jetty question), configured like this:

```
val loginService = new RepoLoginService(usersRepository, signInsRepo)

val server = new Server(8080)
server.addBean(loginService)

val security = new ConstraintSecurityHandler()
server.setHandler(security)

val constraint = new Constraint()
constraint.setName("auth")
constraint.setAuthenticate(true)
constraint.setRoles(Array[String]("user", "admin"))

val mapping = new ConstraintMapping()
mapping.setPathSpec("/*")
mapping.setConstraint(constraint)

security.setConstraintMappings(Collections.singletonList(mapping))
security.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator())
security.setLoginService(loginService)

val mapper = prepareJacksonObjectMapper

val listAccountsController = new ContextHandler("/api/accounts")
listAccountsController.setHandler(new ListAccountsController(mapper, accountsRepository))

val importBankAccountsController = new ContextHandler("/api/bank-account-transactions/import")
importBankAccountsController.setHandler(new ImportBankAccountTransactionsController(mapper, bankAccountTransactionsRepo))

val contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection()
contexts.setHandlers(Array(listAccountsController, importBankAccountsController))

security.setHandler(contexts)

server.start()
server.join()
```

Notice the context for the `listAccountsController`: `/api/accounts`. When I curl `/api/accounts`, I receive a redirect to `/api/accounts/` (note the trailing slash):

```
$ curl --silent --verbose --user francois:francois http://localhost:8080/api/accounts
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'francois'
> GET /api/accounts HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic ZnJhbmNvaXM6ZnJhbmNvaXM=
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Sun, 22 May 2016 03:54:44 GMT
< Location: http://localhost:8080/api/accounts/
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I tried adding a call to `clearAliasChecks()`, which I'm not sure is even related to this. I also tried changing `mapping.setPathSpec("/*")` to `mapping.setPathSpec("/")`, because I read an [answer on Tomcat not adding the trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20729320/7355), but this probably doesn't apply to me anyway.

What must I change to prevent the trailing slash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have defined your Contexts is the reason for that.

A `ContextHandler` is a "root" to a set of resources, and that root is defined to always be a resource directory (in structure).

Since you defined `ContextHandler("/api/accounts")` and accessed `/api/accounts` the implementation "helps" you by making `/api/accounts/` the correct Context root.

Imagine this ...

- You have `val b = ContextHandler("/a/b")`
- You have `val a = ContextHandler("/a")` - which implements (internally) support for sub-resource `/b`
- If you request `/a/b`, which context are you in? - Per spec, you are in context `a`
- If you request `/a/b/`, then you are in context `b`

Comment: That does not answer OPs question. He wanted to know how to get around that. As do I, for various reasons.

Comment: @kevr the answer is to not rely on context root to accomplish that goal.  keep your context root at "/" and your implementations can do whatever you want them to do.