# Mura CMS URL Rewrite (trailing /) in Docker Image

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, docker, docker-compose, mura

I am using Blue River's latest docker image, run docker-compose to start it up and deployed a site bundle in Mura CMS.

The problem is that when I visit a page without a forward slash trailing the URL, I get a 404 instead of a redirect. I've removed the txt from web.config.txt and htaccess.txt and also tried adding some .htaccess rules to add a trailing slash (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844543/4035702).

I think I may have to change a tomcat setting within docker to add the trailing slash, specifically the parameter here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400627/4035702.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Blue River issued a new docker image that solved the rewrite problem. Links attached if interested.

https://github.com/blueriver/MuraCMS/issues/2661

https://github.com/blueriver/MuraCMS/commit/0eb44ad4818f9e089c78152207cc555ba595b6bb