# How to stop Tomcat from redirecting root URL path and adding a slash?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, tomcat9

I created a Java web application and deployed the WAR (`myapp.war`) to Tomcat. When I hit the URL:

`http://server.com/myapp`

Tomcat redirects the browser to:

`http://server.com/myapp/`

How do I stop that? I don't want it to add the slash. I want my servlet to handle the request at `/myapp`.

My servlet mapping in `web.xml` looks like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>  
    <url-pattern>/other</url-pattern>
    ...
```

I thought the empty pattern would get the root URL (`/myapp`) and let me handle it myself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400627/3511123 (`mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled` config attribute)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and I have that attribute set, but it's still adding the "/".

Comment: did you add @WebServlet("/Path") annotation to your servlet ?

Comment: No, I'm not using annotations.