# Tomcat mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled attribute is not working

Tags: tomcat, attributes, tomcat9, mapper, context.xml

Within Tomcat 9 I am trying to enable mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled.  This is a common attributes within context.xml.  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html

I found this [Tomcat is not adding trailing slash to web app's context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055608/tomcat-is-not-adding-trailing-slash-to-web-apps-context)

Which indicated that I should be using

```
<Context mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled="false" />
```

Within the context.xml I added both of these:

```
<Context mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled="false" />    <Context mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled="false" />
```

And restarted the server and still adding the trailing / when i launch my web application.

When my web app loads i see the following:

> WARNING: No rules found matching [Context/Context]

Is there something i am missing to disable this attribute ?

Comment: This is baffling now.